# not all code paths return a value Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting an Compilation Error with my CS file. I have a method that creates a JSON object of the user credentials.

```
public string CreateLoginjson(string strErrorType, bool blIsAuthenticated)
        {

            StringBuilder sbLoginJson = new StringBuilder();
            if (blIsAuthenticated)
            {
                sbLoginJson.Append("{LoginSuccess:1");
            }
            else
            {
                sbLoginJson.Append("{LoginSuccess:0");
            }

            if (strErrorType != string.Empty)
            {
                if (strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "Token" || strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "BlankToken")
                {
                    sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber1:\"Error\"");
                    sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber2:\"Error\"");
                    sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber3:\"Error\"");
                    sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber4:\"Error\"");

                }


                if (strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "Password" || strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "BlankPassword")
                {
                    sbLoginJson.Append(",txtPassword:\"Error\"");

                }

                if (strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "UserName" || strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "BlankUserName")
                {
                    {
                        sbLoginJson.Append(",UserName:\"Error\"");

                    }
                    string strLoadErrorControlMessage = LoadErrorControl(strErrorType, string.Empty);

                    if (strLoadErrorControlMessage != string.Empty)
                    {
                        PageTestApplicationLogin objPageTestApplicationLogin = new PageTestApplicationLogin(objClientConfiguration);
                        sbLoginJson.Append(",ErrorMessage:'" + objPageTestApplicationLogin.GetTestApplicationLoginErrorHtml("", strLoadErrorControlMessage).Replace("'", "\"") + "'");

                    }

                }
                sbLoginJson.Append("}");

                var LoginJson = sbLoginJson.ToString();
                return LoginJson;

            }
        }
```

Should I place the return statement elsewhere, cos I feel that's what's causing this error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You test `if (strErrorType != string.Empty)`. But what about if the condition is `false`? What does your method return in this case? Nothing.

That's what cause the compilation error. You **must** return something, even if it's `null`.

Alternatively, you can also raise an exception. For example, you can add :

```
else {
    throw new ArgumentException("strErrorType", "strErrorType cannot be empty");
}
```

Going further that simply solving the compilation issue, what is your method supposed to do? You test the emptiness of the strErrorType variable. Should it be disallowed? If yes, throw the exception. If no, return an adequate value (`null` probably)

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't true then there is no return from the method.

```
if (strErrorType != string.Empty)
```

So make sure to do something at the end, perhaps throw exception or return something?

Answer (score 0):

you're right the error is happening because if the code doesn't enter the second `if` statment it will never hit the return statement.

I would do this;

```
public string CreateLoginjson(string strErrorType, bool blIsAuthenticated)
        {

            StringBuilder sbLoginJson = new StringBuilder();
            if (blIsAuthenticated)
            {
                sbLoginJson.Append("{LoginSuccess:1");
            }
            else
            {
                sbLoginJson.Append("{LoginSuccess:0");
            }

            if (strErrorType != string.Empty)
            {
               //All your error code here

            }


            var LoginJson = sbLoginJson.ToString();
            return LoginJson;
        }
```

Note the placement of the last two lines outside of the `IF` statement

Answer (score 0):

Your method is returning something only if some condition is met `(if (strErrorType != string.Empty))`. It should also return something if that condition is not met. In other words, if a method has return type, it *must* return something in any case. Unless exception is thrown...

Answer (score 0):

public string CreateLoginjson(string strErrorType, bool blIsAuthenticated)
        {

```
        StringBuilder sbLoginJson = new StringBuilder();
        if (blIsAuthenticated)
        {
            sbLoginJson.Append("{LoginSuccess:1");
        }
        else
        {
            sbLoginJson.Append("{LoginSuccess:0");
        }

        if (strErrorType != string.Empty)
        {
            if (strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "Token" || strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "BlankToken")
            {
                sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber1:\"Error\"");
                sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber2:\"Error\"");
                sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber3:\"Error\"");
                sbLoginJson.Append(",txtTestTokenNumber4:\"Error\"");

            }


            if (strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "Password" || strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "BlankPassword")
            {
                sbLoginJson.Append(",txtPassword:\"Error\"");

            }

            if (strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "UserName" || strErrorType.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) == "BlankUserName")
            {
                {
                    sbLoginJson.Append(",UserName:\"Error\"");

                }
                string strLoadErrorControlMessage = LoadErrorControl(strErrorType, string.Empty);

                if (strLoadErrorControlMessage != string.Empty)
                {
                    PageTestApplicationLogin objPageTestApplicationLogin = new PageTestApplicationLogin(objClientConfiguration);
                    sbLoginJson.Append(",ErrorMessage:'" + objPageTestApplicationLogin.GetTestApplicationLoginErrorHtml("", strLoadErrorControlMessage).Replace("'", "\"") + "'");

                }

            }
            sbLoginJson.Append("}");

            var LoginJson = sbLoginJson.ToString();
            return LoginJson;

        }

return ""; // need it
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the answers solving your problem, I just wanted to add one bit of helpful information.

Instead of checking `strErrorType != string.Empty` you should strongly consider `String.IsNullOrEmpty(strErrorType)` or at least checking for strErrorType != null at some point.

The reasoning is if `strErrorType` is null, it will pass your current test and you will be trying to call methods on a null string, which will throw an exception.